# What is the best way add basic password protection to a simple Next.js web app on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, next.js, cryptojs, vercel

I'm trying to add a simple password validation step to a dashboard that only me and a couple other people would look at. It's not super sensitive data, but I wanted to add a basic protection so that not just anyone can look at it. It's almost definitely not going to be targeted by hackers or anything, so I'm not too concerned about making this completely impenetrable—just good enough.

So I set a secret environment variable on Vercel with a password, and then in `getStaticProps()` I'm hashing it, and passing the hash as a prop to the page. Then on the client side, I hash the user's entered password, and if the two hashes match, do / show some other stuff.

I imagine that the biggest flaw here is that someone could easily go into the developer tools and just set whatever flag I use to determine if the hash of the entered password and the real one match to true.

Am I correct about that being the biggest security flaw here?

Are there any simple additional steps of "obfuscation" I could add to this to make it a little bit harder to get through, or is there any "frontend-only" / simple serverless way to accomplish what I want?

I'm a frontend developer, so I'm a bit out of my depth with creating proper backend authentication or anything, and I realize this is probably pretty laughably insecure. All the guides I'm finding are for fully-fledged user account creation and authentication and things like that. And Vercel has an option to password protect a deployment, but it's $150 per month and I don't want to pay that for this tiny project.

This is probably a really stupid approach, but again, this isn't super sensitive data, so even if only web developers or people who would know how to read JavaScript can break in, then I'm probably fine with that for now.

Here's what my `/pages/index.js` file looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
var crypto = require("crypto");

const IndexPage = ({ pwHash }) => {
  const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [correctPassword, setCorrectPassword] = useState(false);

  const handlePassword = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setEnteredPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const checkPassword = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const enteredHash = crypto
      .createHash("md5")
      .update(enteredPassword)
      .digest("hex");

    if (pwHash === enteredHash) {
      alert("success");
      setCorrectPassword(true);
    } else {
      setEnteredPassword("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {correctPassword && <div>SECRET STUFF</div>}
      <div>
        <h1>
          Testing page
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={checkPassword}>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={enteredPassword}
            onChange={handlePassword}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const pw = process.env.PW;
  const hash = crypto.createHash("md5").update(pw).digest("hex");

  return {
    props: {
      pwHash: hash,
    },
  };
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom domain for this site (anything other than the default `*.vercel.app`), [Octauthent](https://octauthent.com/) can help you password protect your web app.

Octauthent is a no-code solution, and it's free (with premium features).

[Here is a detailed tutorial](https://octauthent.medium.com/password-protect-your-vercel-site-with-octauthent-1f79e37b1d91) for websites hosted on Vercel